# How to insert html code just before <input in cakephp helper

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, cakephp-2.1

I have this block of code in a login .ctp file:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('AdmUser', array(
    'class' => 'form-vertical',
    'inputDefaults' => array(
        'label' => false,
        'div' => false,
    ))); ?>

<?php echo $this->Form->input('login', array(
    'placeholder' => 'User')
    );?>
```

I'm using [slywalker's](https://github.com/slywalker/TwitterBootstrap) TwitterBootstrap plugin for cakephp so the output is like this:

```
<div class="control-group">
     <div class="controls">
          <input name="data[AdmUser][login]" placeholder="User" maxlength="15" type="text" id="AdmUserLogin" required="required">
     </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to put some html code just before input tag like this:

```
<div class="control-group">
     <div class="controls">
          <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-user"></i></span>
          <input name="data[AdmUser][login]" placeholder="User" maxlength="15" type="text" id="AdmUserLogin" required="required">
     </div>
</div>
```

When i try to use `'before' => '<span class="add-on"><i class="icon-lock"></i></span>'` the code goes between `<div class="control-group">` and
     `<div class="controls">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the examples in the readme of the plugin?

https://github.com/slywalker/TwitterBootstrap/blob/master/README.md

I haven't tested it, but it seems the plugin uses 'prepend' and 'append' options to add these kind of options; if these options are set, the FormHelper internally generated these tags using this method;

[BootstrapFormHelper::addOn()](https://github.com/slywalker/TwitterBootstrap/blob/master/View/Helper/BootstrapFormHelper.php#L42)

Comment: Thanks, that's the answer that solves my problem, just adding `'prepend' => '<i class="icon-user"></i>'` in the options array of the  Form->input, generates the code the way i want.

Answer (score 1):

I have tested my code to the CakePhp version cakephp-2.6.6.

```
echo $this->Form->input(
    'login', 
    array(
    'between' =>'<span class="add-on"><i class="icon-lock"></i></span>',
    'after'=>'',
    'placeholder' => 'User'
    )
);
```

And which produces:

```
<span class="add-on"><i class="icon-lock"></i></span>
<input type="text" id="AdmUserLogin" placeholder="User" name="data[AdmUser][login]">
```

You have custom form helper I think that's why you got

```
<div class="control-group">
     <div class="controls">
```

Code before input field and your **'before'** tag not working.If you add **'between'** tag it will add code before your input and finally you have to add **'after'** tag to null because you do not need to add extra html after your input field.
Thanks.